# How can I Know the force of a swipe Gesture Recognizers?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I want to move a image to the right or to the left with the swipe gesture recognizer, i´m already moving the image using the CCMoveTo function, but I don´t know how move the image faster or slower depends of the force of the swipe.

If the user make a strong swipe the image should move faster than if the user make a soft swipe.

Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what the property `velocity` in the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is for. You can see an example of how to use it in class 08 (I think) of cs193p by Paul Hegarty. Here's [the link](http://itunes.apple.com/br/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255) to download it from iTunes U

Answer (score 9):

A `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is a one shot thing. It fires when the device detects the gesture and is done after that.

If you want more information about the movement of the finger you should check [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).